# reactjs populating components with my socket dates

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

Hello I would like to know how I fill in html components (h1, div etc etc)
in react with data coming from my socket on nodejs

here is my front - end code:

```
  render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <h1 id="resultado"></h1>
                <div id="player-1" class="user-panel">
                    <p>Nome: <span class="nome"></span></p>
                    <p>Pontos: <span class="pontos">0</span></p>
                    <div class="botoes">
                        <button>Pedra</button>
                        <button>Papel</button>
                        <button>Tesoura</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jogada"></div>
                </div>

                <br />
                <br />
                <br />

                <div id="player-2" class="user-panel">
                    <p>Nome: <span class="nome"></span></p>
                    <p>Pontos: <span class="pontos">0</span></p>
                    <div class="botoes">
                        <button>Pedra</button>
                        <button>Papel</button>
                        <button>Tesoura</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jogada"></div>
                </div>

                <p id="espera"></p>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I wanted to pass data from my socket to my components with class ids

I know that in html I would call my script and solve the problem, but what would it look like in nodejs?

Comment: SO needs to be used a last resort when you have done the research, have tried to achieve the desired output and actually cannot progress without assistance. You are posting questions continuously, many of which can be solved a quick read of the docs and some attempt. Again, you posting incredibly broad questions that highlight little attempt has been made to resolve the issue.

Comment: I really looked for it and I didn't find it, and it's not very wide I just wanted to know how I give my tag a socket value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consuming data is no different from any other API call. Simply get the results in your socket event handler and manipulate it as needed.

Below is an example of getting user data and updating the state which will render the list of users.

```
let socket = null;

function App() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    function updateUsers(users) {
        setUsers(users);
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        function connect() {
            socket = io('http://localhost:3000', {
                autoConnect: false
            });

            socket.on('connect', () => {
                socket
                    .emit('authenticate', {token: window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')})
                    .on('authenticated', () => {

                        socket.on('chat:users-get', (message) => {
                            updateUsers(message.data);
                        });

                        socket.emit('chat:users-get');
                    })
                    .on('unauthorized', (msg) => {
                        console.error(`socket not authenticated ${msg}`);
                    });
            });

            socket.open();
        }

        connect();

    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <fieldset id="users-container">
                <legend>Users Online</legend>
                <div>{users.length} Online</div>
                <ul>
                    {users.map(user => (
                        <li key={user.username}>{user.username}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks, 
about socket.open Is it my impression or would it work without socket.open?
 What he does ?

Comment: You can connect automatically if you removed the `autoConnect: false` option

Comment: u can help me with this @Samuel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59003772/communication-with-io-socket-using-react-and-node